# Can 40Ca II decay or change into something different

Tags: temperature, elements, isotopes

I just read the Wiki article on calcium isotopes and it said the stable calcium isotopes such as 40Ca have never been observed to decay. Then, despite the high temperature of stars such as Sun there are calcium ions floating on the chromosphere of Sun. I thought calcium will be vaporized or even turned into plasma if it is exposed to extreme heat.

My main question is, is calcium for example 40Ca II is indestructible or at least can't be change to something different? If 40Ca II can indeed be change to something different like maybe carbon, helium, potassium, etc. what is the level of temperature that is required to achieve that?

Comment: Those calcium ions observed in stars are already vaporized.  Vaporization has nothing to do with radioactive decay, nor do ions in a plasma state.  When water molecules vaporize from the liquid state, the vapor still consists of water molecules.

Comment: Is it possible to change ionized 40Ca into something that is no longer a calcium perhaps by extreme force, etc.?

Comment: I saw one article on the internet that they got `Ca` to emit protons by bombarding it with alpha particles.  But that is not spontaneous decay with a rise in temperature.

Comment: But the Ca still remain, right? How about if there is no longer anything that is related to calcium? How about in the core of stars?

Comment: If Ca emits protons, it is no longer Ca.

Comment: Other than that, what other processes that can turn 40Ca ii into different elements?

Comment: Calcium atoms can't withstand extreme heat according to this link. http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/ast122/lectures/lec09.html

"If the collision is strong enough (high temperatures) then the electron is knocked off the atom and we say the atom is ionized. So as we go from low temperatures in stars (couple 1,000K) we see heavy atoms, like calcium and magnesium, in the stars spectrum. As the temperature increases, we see lighter atoms, such as hydrogen (the heavier atoms are all ionized by this point and have no electrons to produce absorption lines)." Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you should read up on the difference between ionization and nuclear decay.

Comment: @Bill Watts but those processes are almost similar that involved destruction of atoms and change them into different elements, isn't it?

Comment: That's wrong.  Why don't you also read the difference between atoms and nuclei.  Protons, not electrons determine the element.

Comment: @Bill Watts Ok thanks, will read it later. But in the link I shared, calcium will get destroyed if the temperature is too high that only lighter atoms (e.g hydrogen) remain. This is ionization, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish the significantly different energy scales at which the phenomena take place. Vaporisation happens near melting temperature. Ca melts at 842C and boils at 1484C. Plasma formation requires ionisation that is 6.11 eV or 70.000 C/K. Thermal fusion of 40Ca with for example 4He requires even much higher temperatures combined with very high pressure.

Comment: Is it possible to change 40Ca II to smaller nuclei that it is no longer 40Ca II but wholly different kind of something that is no longer calcium?

Comment: It can be neutron activated to give 37Ar. See https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.researchgate.net/figure/Reaction-cross-section-for-the-40-Can-a-37-Ar-reaction-For-thermal-neutrons-a-1-v-law_fig2_51605647/amp

Comment: That's fusion, how about if splitting any calcium including 40Ca ii into different elements?